# become_user not working in Ansible when specifying become: true

Tags: ansible

I have this playbook in ansible and for some reason, in task *01. change to gpadmin user and enable gpperfmon collection* is not becoming user gpadmin and I get the following error:

```
fatal: [root@192.168.1.100]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "gpperfmon_install --enable --password HulkMon --port 5432", "delta": "0:00:00.002733", "end": "2022-11-07 12:57:33.549152", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2022-11-07 12:57:33.546419", "stderr": "/bin/sh: **gpperfmon_install: command not found**", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: gpperfmon_install: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}


#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
---

- hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - vars/gpdb.yml
  remote_user: root
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: "00. check whether can connect internet"
      shell: |
        ping -c 1 -w 1 www.google.com > /dev/null; \
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then \
           echo "[ERROR]: host can not connect internet world!"; \
           exit 1; \
        fi

    - name: 01. change to gpadmin user and enable gpperfmon collection
      shell: gpperfmon_install --enable --password mypass --port 5432
      become: true
      become_user: gpadmin
```

When I run this command on the target server using gpadmin user, it works, if I run it under root, I get the same error I'm getting in Ansible so I assume it is using root and not changing

What did I miss?

Comment: How did you conclude ansible is not becoming the user you configured? The error is `gpperfmon_install: command not found`, there's nothing related to not being able to switch user.

Comment: When I run this command using the gpadmin user, it works, when I run this as root, I get "command not found". I just clarified this in the question, thanks

Comment: Probably because either you `$PATH` is not the same when you are using interactive login, or because you are using `bash` as your shell when the `shell` module uses `sh` as default.

Comment: My guess: the path where this command resides is set in your user's `bashrc`. Ansible uses sh by default and does read any initialization files.

Comment: it was the path, I just sourced it: source /home/gpadmin/.bashrc

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Zeitounator

I was missing to source the bashrc

```
- name: 00. change to gpadmin user and enable gpperfmon collection
  shell: source /home/gpadmin/.bashrc && gpperfmon_install --enable --password mypass --port 5432
  become: yes
  become_user: gpadmin
```